# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '30.6.4.10006' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my query. My issue is that if I simply use the statement and t1.DisplayVersion >= '30.6.4.10006' it returns smaller values as it's only looking a the first character.  For example, any computers with version 8.23.2500 are returned.

```
select distinct v1.guid
from vComputer v1
inner join Inv_AddRemoveProgram t1 on v1.Guid = t1._ResourceGuid
where t1.DisplayName like 'Cisco WebEx Meeting Center%' 
  and CAST(t1.DisplayVersion AS INT) >= '30.6.4.10006'
  and t1.installflag = '1' 
  and v1.IsManaged = '1'
```

Comment: Surprised? That value isn't an integer...

Comment: And what exactly were you expecting it to convert to?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Starting with SQL Server 2012 there is the function `PARSENAME`, which is designed to "read" version numbers up to 4 parts separated by dots. Might be helpfull...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My issue is if I just say and t1.displayversion >= '30.6.4.10006' it returns some versions less than 30.6.4.10006 because it only looks at the first character so for example version 8.23.2500 is returned.  I guess I should really be trying to convert to decimal but I've tried and not having any luck so far...

Answer (score 0):

In string comparisons, '30' is less than '8' because it compares the individual characters in the same position and 3 is less than 8.  To do a numeric comparison, you'll need to parse the text into separate fields using a splitter function, align the items and then compare them.  This will not be very simple and will not likely perform very well across any significant number of rows.

It will be simpler and perform better if you can get away with comparing the digits in front of the second decimal point; 30.6 vs 8.23.  Those values can be converted to decimal and directly compared.

```
--COMPARE JUST THE FIRST TWO
DECLARE @t TABLE (VersionNumber VARCHAR(50));
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(50) = '8.23.2500';
INSERT INTO @t (VersionNumber)
VALUES ('30.6.4.10006'),
('1.2.3.4'),
('100.200.300.400'),
('1.200.3.4'),
('100.2.3.4'),
('8.24.2500'),
('8.23.2501'),
('8.23.2499'),
('8.23');

SELECT  t.VersionNumber, @test,
        FirstTwo = TRY_CONVERT(decimal(20,2),LEFT(t.VersionNumber, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.', t.VersionNumber, CHARINDEX('.', t.VersionNumber) + 1), 0) - 1, 8000))),
        FirstTwoTest = TRY_CONVERT(decimal(20,2),LEFT(@test, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.', @test, CHARINDEX('.', @test) + 1), 0) - 1, 8000)))
FROM    @t AS t
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(decimal(20,2),LEFT(t.VersionNumber, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.', t.VersionNumber, CHARINDEX('.', t.VersionNumber) + 1), 0) - 1, 8000)))
 > TRY_CONVERT(decimal(20,2),LEFT(@test, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.', @test, CHARINDEX('.', @test) + 1), 0) - 1, 8000)))
;
```

Comment: If I have some free time, I may take a crack at comparing the full string.

Comment: Thanks but I can't get away with comparing the first two.  The previous version was 30.6.0.10050 so it would see that version and the latest version 30.6.4.10006 as equal...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive CTE version.  I THINK it will work as it returned the correct results for the limited test data.  You'll need to do some more extensive testing and figure out how to incorporate it into your solution.

In summary, it splits the strings using [Jeff Moden's](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) splitter function, then compares the values based on the ordinal, using a recursive cte to drill into the results for which the new value is greater or equal to the existing value.  Finally, it selects from the original source where the new value was greater then the existing value.

With my sample data, the following versions came back as newer than 8.23.2500:

30.6.4.10006

100.200.300.400

100.2.3.4

8.24.2500

8.23.2501

The following versions came back as not newer than 8.23.2500:

1.2.3.4

1.200.3.4

8.23.2499

8.23

8.23.2500

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #test;
GO

DECLARE @t TABLE (VersionNumber VARCHAR(50));
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(50) = '8.23.2500';
INSERT INTO @t (VersionNumber)
VALUES ('30.6.4.10006'),
('1.2.3.4'),
('100.200.300.400'),
('1.200.3.4'),
('100.2.3.4'),
('8.24.2500'),
('8.23.2501'),
('8.23.2499'),
('8.23'), 
('8.23.2500');

SELECT  dsk.ItemNumber,
        Item = CAST(dsk.Item AS INT)
INTO    #TEST
FROM    Utility.DelimitedSplit8K(@test, '.') AS dsk;

WITH cte
AS (SELECT  t.VersionNumber,
            t2.ItemNumber,
            LeftItem = dsk.Item,
            RightItem = t2.Item,
            Diff = dsk.Item - t2.Item
    FROM    @t AS t
      CROSS APPLY Utility.DelimitedSplit8K(t.VersionNumber, '.') AS dsk
      INNER JOIN #TEST AS t2
        ON dsk.ItemNumber = t2.ItemNumber
        WHERE t2.ItemNumber = 1
        AND dsk.Item - t2.Item > -1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  t.VersionNumber,
            t2.ItemNumber,
            LeftItem = dsk.Item,
            RightItem = t2.Item,
            Diff = dsk.Item - t2.Item
    FROM    @t AS t
      CROSS APPLY Utility.DelimitedSplit8K(t.VersionNumber, '.') AS dsk
      INNER JOIN #TEST AS t2
        ON dsk.ItemNumber = t2.ItemNumber
        INNER JOIN cte
        ON cte.ItemNumber +1 = t2.ItemNumber
        AND cte.VersionNumber = t.VersionNumber
        WHERE cte.Diff > -1
        )

        SELECT * FROM @t AS t
        WHERE t.VersionNumber IN 
        (    
            SELECT cte.VersionNumber FROM cte
            WHERE cte.Diff > 0
        )
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
select distinct v1.guid
from vComputer v1
inner join Inv_AddRemoveProgram t1 on v1.Guid = t1._ResourceGuid
where t1.DisplayName like 'Cisco WebEx Meeting Center%' 
  and CAST(Replace(t1.DisplayVersion,'.','') AS BIGINT) >= 306410006
  and t1.installflag = '1' 
  and v1.IsManaged = '1'
```

Comment: 30.6.4.10006 is not a numeric value and cannot be converted to float.

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error, "Error converting data type varchar to float"

Comment: You can't convert  '30.6.4.10006'  to 306410006. How do you justify whether version is '30.6.4.10006' or '3.06.4.10006' ?  In this case, your query will treat it as the same, which is a very big flaw.

Comment: I get the following error when running the query with CASE\REPLACE Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The conversion of the nvarchar value '29133410019' overflowed an int column.

Comment: @jfatal it doesn't matter what data type you use, your answer is wrong.

Comment: @jfatal the following versions are returned with that query                        28.12.1.16851
28.12.20.10001
29.13.34.10019
30.6.4.10006